# Angular 7, after reset form, form is always valid while it should be invalid as it was in initial state

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form with validation, i need reset form after submit but once reset the form it show always valid and submit button get enabled while it should be disabled.

please check this url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khuke7

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.myForm.reset();` for resetting the form.
The form now resets, all the input fields go back to their initial state and any valid, touched or dirty properties are also reset to their starting values.

Comment: Thanks @nircraft, it's working now, problem was custom space validation so after reset form it was showing error - Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null so i have added a condition to check null also

Comment: But why custom space validation checked automatically each time while it should happen only for username field when touch it?

Answer (score 0):

Reset takes form to the newly created state, apply validation at the untouched level to achieve validation.